# RaphaelJS Sluggishness after many transformations

Tags: javascript, raphael

So, I have a drag function attached to my elements that, at its core, does a simple transformation to move the element:

```
element.transform("...T" + (dx - element.lastDx) + "," + (dy - element.lastDy));
```

I noticed that if I drag an element around a good bit, it becomes quite choppy. I'm assuming that it is because of the "nested" (...) transformation, but this was the only way that I was able to get the drag to work since if I just use an absolute transformation, the element snaps back to its original position after I release it and then subsequently move it again.

Does anyone have any experience with this and know of a good solution? The sluggishness is really not acceptable for what I'm trying to do, but I've been unsuccessful at getting around it.

UPDATE: Here's a link to a JSFiddle demonstrating the behaviour. I tried to strip out only the dragging logic, but it's a bit messy. There's also logic in there that handles resizing the lines. You'll notice that if you move a line around or resize it a bit, then it becomes super sluggish. I'm sure this is because I'm doing the transformations all wrong, but this is the only way I was able to get it to work.

http://jsfiddle.net/4vLjbyy5/3/

Comment: Is it possible to put a test example on a fiddle or jsbin ? Nested transformations do cause sluggishness. Its not obvious from the code if this is happening though, and also if something else is amiss. Ultimately you could code it so that it takes into account its starting transformation.

Comment: Yeah, I'll break the drag functionality out into a separate little module so I can post it on fiddle and then I'll update the question with a link.

Comment: I posted a link to the JSFiddle.

Comment: Not seeing a particular problem after playing with the fiddle for a while, nothing sluggish for me. Not sure if the transformations are nested as well really. When I looked it just seemed to have one matrix set. What browser are you on, and device, and how much are you dragging it before it gets sluggish ? Where are you seeing the nested transformations in the console or something ?

Comment: I guess nested wasn't the best word, but I meant "relative" transformation rather than absolute. I've noticed the problem in a few different browsers (chrome, FF) and also on my android devices. If I drag one specific line around for a little while, say, 10 seconds, then it becomes very choppy. All the other lines work fine until I drag one of them around for a bit and then it becomes choppy as well. I assumed that it was because it was using the relative transformation (...T) rather than just an absolute transformation (T).